# Spring EmbeddedDatabase with Derby requiring schema

Tags: spring, derby

I'm trying to set up EmbeddedDatabase for testing in Spring and I'm getting the following error: `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'SA' does not exist`.

From the following code:

```
private DataSource dataSource() {
            return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                    .generateUniqueName(true)
                    .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.DERBY)
                    .addScript("tables_data.sql")
                    .build();
        }
```

SQL is:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
     id    BIGSERIAL,
     name  varchar(200)
);
```

Been searching around for few hours. Haven't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried simply [creating an SA schema](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.5/ref/rrefsqlj31580.html)? Honestly I have never used Derby, but one thing I've learned is that any time you use two frameworks together there will always be little quirks.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `CREATE SCHEMA` line to the top of your SQL. So your SQL should look like this:

```
CREATE SCHEMA SA;

CREATE TABLE person (
     id    BIGSERIAL,
     name  varchar(200)
);
```