# Spring Boot auto-generated data source with EmbeddedDatabase Derby leads to "Schema '<schema-name>' does not exist"

Tags: spring-boot, datasource, derby, auto-generate, embedded-database

I do use Spring Boot 1.4.2 in combination with profile dependent auto-generated data sources based on the configuration of an "application-{profile}.properties" file and the JAR dependencies Spring Boot detects on the classpath:

Maven Spring Boot dependencies in "**pom.xml**":

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Spring Boot "**application-dev.properties**":

```
# JPA (JpaBaseConfiguration, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration)
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.database=default
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl

# DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=false
spring.datasource.generate-unique-name=false
```

When starting the Spring Boot application where Hibernate should auto-generate the Derby DDL and the underlying schema [I get the same error reported here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38272091/spring-embeddeddatabase-with-derby-requiring-schema):

> **java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Schema 'SA' does not exist**

The generated JDBC Derby URL and username looks like:

- url=jdbc:derby:memory:testdb;create=true;
- username=sa

**Important**: When switching the default "**spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto**" from "**create-drop**" to "**update**" the DDL execution works. But: according to the [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-jpa-properties), "**create-drop**" is the **default setting** for embedded databases (like DERBY) - even when not having configured "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" explicitly.

Once the DDL creation passed using "update" setting, a preceding run with "create-drop" works successfully.

Is there a way where the auto-generated data source approach in Spring Boot can work with "create-drop" for embedded databases like DERBY initially without using this workaround?

Comment: Now, I opened a bug report below: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7706